# Creating a 3D array using elements (excluding the first one) in a 2D array

Tags: ruby

I have a 2D array:

```
[["abc","def"],["ghi","jkl","mno"]]
```

I want to create a new array (a 3D array?) inside each inner array and around its elements except the first one like this:

```
[["abc",["def"]],["ghi",["jkl","mno"]]]
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
arr = [["abc","def"],["ghi","jkl","mno"]]

arr.map { |first, *rest| [first, rest] }
  #=> [["abc", ["def"]], ["ghi", ["jkl", "mno"]]]
```